Understanding Quran 6:40, 17:67, 29:65
As salamu walikum rahmatullahi barakatuh
How to understand these verses, Allah says during hardship such as during sailing if polytheist come across hardship, they would ignore their idols and call upon Allah.
But let say a Hindu, he will call upon Krishna or ram, Christian will call upon Jesus, atheist might not call upon any god.
How to understand these verses?

The context of these passages are about the polytheists of Hijaz.
Though one could argue that there are no "mushriks or mulhids in foxholes", it is more correct to say the clear aspect of the passages are about the Arab polytheists.

Thank you for the answer. That's what I thought too but reading Ibn Kathir it seemed as if the verse is addressing everyone. By any chance you have any scholars opinion that states this pretaining to pegan Arabs.

You looking for any scholar's interpretation or a specific time period?
Because lots of people will say something as follows:

First and foremost its an address the audience (Quranic Mushrikuun)
We can take from the passage and expand it to a broader context.


Any scholar that's reliable and been accepted by the ummah. Any classical or contemporary
